# server returned HTTP response code 503

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm getting this error when trying to build on cordova using node. I'm behind a proxy and I've already set that up. Here is the screenshot. What am I missing.

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_71 
Running: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease 
-b C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\platforms\android\build.gradle 
-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true 
Downloading http:// services. gradle. org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http:// services.gradle. org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
 at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://services. gradle. org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
... 3 more C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126 throw e; 
^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease 
-b C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\platforms\android\build.gradle 
-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true" 
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project 
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please show your `AsyncTask` or downloading code

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You can choose 1 or 2

1. Download gradle from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip and paste it in your App\platforms\android\gradle and the edit build.js in App\platforms\android\cordova\lib and change var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';             to var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=../gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';
2. Change var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'; to var distributionUrl = 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';